# Process function definition c#

Tags: c#

i am still learning c# and .net core. Some time ago one guy send to me a exercise on which unfortunately i fall off mainly because of this function definition :

**public static (int UserId, decimal MaximumTotalInstallment)[] Process(User[] users) {}**

This is a library function which is used in XUnit test class in another namespace :

```
var expected = new[] {(1, 100m), (2, 1000m)};
        
// when
var output = BatchProcessingLibraryClass.Process(input);
        
// then
output.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Could You please tell me what this call of lib function exactly do ? I dont meet this kind of function declaration before.

Comment: `(int UserId, decimal MaximumTotalInstallment)` is named *tuple* which contains two properties: `int UserId` and `decimal MaximumTotalInstallment`. Then when adding `[]` we have *array* of named tuples: `(int UserId, decimal MaximumTotalInstallment)[]`. I hope that `User[] users` is clear: array of `User`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell what it does from the name (other than "process"), but you can tell what inputs are expected and what outputs are produced

- **Inputs** - An array of `User` type called `users`.
- **Output** - An array of a tuple. This tuple has two fields an integer named `UserId` and a decimal named `MaximumTotalInstallment`. This type is equivalent to `ValueTuple<int,decimal>`.

*Other* notes, the method is `static` which means it is called not for a particular instance of a class, but callable (like a library) from anywhere else.